# Problem calling C++ Class method from Rust

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

The following code is generated by bindgen.

```
extern "C" {
    #[doc = "MoraComm Properties"]
    #[link_name = "\u{1}_ZN22MoraCommManagerWrapped10propertiesEj"]
    pub fn MoraCommManagerWrapped_properties(
        this: *mut MoraCommManagerWrapped,
        deviceNumber: ::std::os::raw::c_uint,
    ) -> MoraCommPropertiesWrapped;
}

impl MoraCommManagerWrapped {
    #[inline]
    pub unsafe fn properties(
        &mut self,
        deviceNumber: ::std::os::raw::c_uint,
    ) -> MoraCommPropertiesWrapped {
        MoraCommManagerWrapped_properties(self, deviceNumber)
    }
    #[inline]
    pub unsafe fn new() -> Self {
        let mut __bindgen_tmp = ::std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
        MoraCommManagerWrapped_MoraCommManagerWrapped(__bindgen_tmp.as_mut_ptr());
        __bindgen_tmp.assume_init()
    }
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut mgr: MoraCommManagerWrapped = MoraCommManagerWrapped::new();
        let p = mgr.properties(0); // <- segfault
    }
}
```

When main is run, there is a segfault.

I added logging on the C++ side, that shows that the value of the `this` pointer is equal to value of the `deviceNumber` arg.

I call another class that is part of the same bindgen generated bindings and it works.

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Without the c++ code, it's anyone's guess. For all we know, the C++ code immediately does something like `(*static_cast<int*>(nullptr)) = 42`

Comment: What exactly is `MoraCommManagerWrapped`?